# Is it possible to lose badges

Tags: support, badges

Is it possible to lose a badge when the statement for recieving stops being true? By this I mean that I get a badge eg. Electorate, but then it becomes false, beacuse 25% of votes are now not on questions. 
Do I lose the badge, or they cannot be lost?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No - you do not lose badges you have earned.

[Definitive answer by Aarobot](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/58055/154443) over on Meta.SE

> No, badges are never taken away. That's part of the site's design.
>
> However, if you no longer meet the criteria for a badge (say your "great question" got busted back down to 99 votes), then you won't earn another one of those badges until you "catch up."

Answer (score 4):

Regular badges never go away. Earned once, you get to keep them. Even if the badge is retired, like "Analytical", which is now replaced by "Informed".

As @Rory Alsop points out, if you no longer meet the criteria for the Good/Nice/Great Question/Answer badges, you will keep them, but you won't earn them again - the next time you earn them, the new badge effectively replaces the old one that you already had.

Tag badges however, *can* go away. They cannot be replaced in this way, as they are specific to a tag.